# Explain inspect.getargspec(map) under Python 3.4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

I am confused by the behavior of Python's builtin map under `inspect.getargspec` in Python3.4.

```
In [1]: import inspect

In [2]: inspect.getargspec(map)
Out[2]: ArgSpec(args=[], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)

In [3]: import sys

In [4]: sys.version_info 
Out[4]: sys.version_info(major=3, minor=4, micro=0, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

It says that there aren't any arguments.  It used to just err, this was preferable.

In particular I'm trying to learn how many arguments a function requires.  My old technique was to return the length of argspec.args if varargs, and defaults were simple.  This technique returns a wrong result here though.

Answer (score 1):

`getargspec()` calls `getfullargspec()` that has its docstring changed in Python 3.4 to specify that 'callable object' is accepted -- it was 'function' in the past. `map` is not a function but it is a callable (returns `map` objects) therefore there is no error.

The update might be connected with the introduction of [Argument Clinic in Python 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3.4/whatsnew/3.4.html#whatsnew-pep-436) i.e., some builtin callables can be introspected now e.g.:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getargspec(binascii.a2b_uu)
ArgSpec(args=['data'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)
```

It works in Python 3.4 but it fails in Python 3.3

`map` object is not documented using argument clinic. It uses [custom code to parse input args](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2b18f6c37a68/Python/bltinmodule.c#l1001). The correct behaviour would be to raise `ValueError("unsupported callable")` (not `TypeError`).